# Facebook SDK - Access Wall Posts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing some unusual problem, I'm integrating Facebook SDK in my iOS app, The main purpose of the app is to access Wall Posts (public), I have successfully integrated SDK & everything works for me (for my facebook id) but when I give the app to someone else he/she can't access his/her wall posts access-token & everything is the same. The unusual part is if I add that same user in Roles Section of Facebook Developer section of my app, the apps works for them too.

Keep in mind I haven't released my app to public so I'm using a beta version of my app & so is every body else in my team.

My question is, is this the normal way of giving access to someone so that they can use our app or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your app is in development mode, only people having a Role in the app (Admins/Developers/Testers) will be able to use it.

Comment: ok, you are talking about facebook app, right? In facebook app store not my iOS app?

Comment: I am talking about https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/roles/. You either add everyone you want to test the app as a tester there or set your app live at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/review-status/

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Guess I have to add everyone